# can get_map in R produce a map with a resolution higher than 640 x 640?

Tags: r, google-maps

I am trying to show school on a map with some legends. It is working fine if it default to 640 x 640 resolution. But when I try to use a higher resolution, it is all mess up. Anyone has any idea why ?
data can be found at: https://www.kaggle.com/nycopendata/high-schools

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
library(ggmap)

school <-read.csv("scores.csv", header=TRUE, sep= ",")

nyc <- c(lon = -74.0059, lat = 40.7128)
nyc_map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -74.0059, lat = 40.7128), zoom = 10, scale = 2 )
ggmap(nyc_map, legend="none") +
geom_point(aes(Longitude, Latitude, color= Average.Score..SAT.Math. , size = school$Student.Enrollment), data = school)

# trying to use higher resolution but it mess up
nyc_map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -74.0059, lat = 40.7128), zoom = 10, scale = 2, size = c(1280, 1280))
ggmap(nyc_map, legend="none") +
geom_point(aes(Longitude, Latitude, color= Average.Score..SAT.Math. , size = school$Student.Enrollment), data = school)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specify units.

Comment: unrelated, but you should use `Student.Enrollment` rather than `school$Student.Enrollment` in the aes

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for those coming from Google: **No, it can't**.

It uses the static maps API from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Which specifies that max size is 640x640 (unless you want to pay).